# Query parameters with url_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
url_for([:edit, @post])
```

is working and generating `/comments/123/edit`. Now I need to add a query parameter, so that instead of

```
/comments/123/edit
```

it is

```
/comments/123/edit?qp=asdf
```

I tried `url_for([:edit, @post], :qp => "asdf")` but no go.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use named routes.

```
edit_post_path(@post, :qp => "asdf")
```

Comment: How can i create an absolute path like that?

Comment: Use the `_url` instead of `_path`: `edit_post_url(@post, :qp => "asdf")`

Answer (score 24):

You can use `polymorphic_path`

```
polymorphic_path([:edit, @post], :qp => 'asdf')
```

Answer (score 19):

You can pass `params` to `url_for`. Checkout it in the sourcecode: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d891c19066bba3a614a27a92d55968174738e755/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L675

Comment: This is not made clear in the api docs. Thank you so much, more upvotes needed.

Comment: still not sure how I would do `polymorphic_url(event, locale: :fr)` for instance, I get `/Users/dorianmariefr/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.3/gems/actionpack-6.1.4.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:515:in `url_for': wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1) (ArgumentError)` with `url_for`

Answer (score 12):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5031632/2809881) from Simone Carletti indeed works, but there are times when one wants to construct the URL using objects as described in the Rails routing guide, and not rely on the `_path` helpers.

The answers from both [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31169551/2809881) and [Swards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32061247/2809881) are attempting to describe exactly how to do this, but for me the syntax used results in an error (using Rails 4.2.2, which has the same behaviour as 4.2.4, which is the current stable release as of this answer).

The correct syntax for creating a URL/path from objects while also passing parameters should be, as opposed to a nested array, rather a flat array containing the URL components, plus a hash as the final element:

`url_for([:edit, @post, my_parameter: "parameter_value"])`

Here the first two elements are parsed as the components for the URL, and the hash is considered as parameter(s) for the URL.

This also works with `link_to`:

`link_to( "Link Text", [:edit, @post, my_parameter: "parameter_value"])`

When I call `url_for` as suggested by Ben & Swards:

`url_for([[:edit, @post], my_parameter: "parameter_value"])`

I get the following error:

`ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'to_model' for #<Array:0x007f5151f87240>)`

The trace shows that this is being called from `polymorphic_routes.rb` in `ActionDispatch::Routing`, via `url_for` from `routing_url_for.rb` (`ActionView::RoutingUrlFor`):

```
gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:297:in `handle_list'
gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:206:in `polymorphic_method'
gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:134:in `polymorphic_path'
gems/actionview-4.2.2/lib/action_view/routing_url_for.rb:99:in `url_for'
```

The problem being, that it's expecting an array of URL components (eg. symbols, model objects, etc), *not* an array containing another array.

Looking at the appropriate [code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/35842aa91883245dbf4270b0fc863684aabf4688/actionview/lib/action_view/routing_url_for.rb#L100) from `routing_url_for.rb`, we can see that when it receives an array which has a hash as the final element, it will then [extract](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/794a70f94485fb64ed1c49ba8532895306e2001c/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/extract_options.rb#L22) the hash and treat as parameters, leaving then just the array with the URL components.

Which is why the flat array with a hash as the last element works, and the nested array does not.