# Rails 4: form_for additional parameters with set of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

In early stage my form_for looked like so:

```
<%= form_for [:dashboard, @article], html: {class: 'article_form'} do |f| %>
```

and it will know already when it's create or update based on the `@article`. But then I needed to add an additional parameter, let's name it `article_type`. And I added it like this in routes:

```
resources :articles, path: 'articles/:article_type', constraints: { type: /image|video/ }
```

Then in [this section of form_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for#1313-Adding-Additional-Parameters-to-form-for) it was mentioned that I can do something like,

```
<%= form_for [:dashboard, @article], url: {article_type: 'image'}, html: {class: 'article_form'} do |f| %>
```

to get what I want, as long as I omit `:controller` or `:action`, it's suppose to generate it correctly. But it seems it's not doing so...

What I keep getting is:

if @article is new

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/dashboard/articles/image/new" class="article_form" id="new_article" method="post">
```

if @article exists:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/dashboard/articles/image/new" class="article_form" id="edit_article_3" method="post">
```

See where it only creates `/new`, that's wrong as action is suppose to be `/dashboard/articles/image` for create and `/dashboard/articles/image/3` if edit.

**EDIT**

Temporary solution I have to make it work

```
<%
  named_route = if @article.new_record?
    dashboard_articles_path(@article, article_type: params[:article_type])
  else
    dashboard_article_path(@article, article_type: params[:article_type])
  end
%>
<%= form_for [:dashboard, @article], url: named_route, html: {class: 'article_form'} do |f| %>
```

Comment: you will have to use a path helper like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031591/query-parameters-with-url-for

Comment: @phoet Temporarily I am using named routes. I'll update question with my temporary solution.