# How to pass parameter in data-url for edit method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= f.select :current_user_insurance_insurance_company, companies_to_be_included, {include_blank:"None"}, class: "select-company", id:"insurance-company", data: { url: url_for([:new, @request, :user_insurance])} %>
```

This is the data-url I have used for new method of insurance, so in order to edit insurance, how can I pass id for insurance in the data url. I tried to pass the id through the following method:

```
{ url: url_for([:edit, @request, :user_insurance])}
```

and this is the error I got:

No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"user_insurances", :format=>nil, :id=>nil, :request_id=>

Comment: please provide whole code... of view

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query parameters with url\_for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031591/query-parameters-with-url-for)

Comment: Do you have a route defined that matches? Sounds like you don't. Post the output of 'rake routes'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply hard-code the link and escape the fuss altogether

```
data: { url: "/requests/#{@request.id}/user_insurances/#{id_you_required}/edit"}
```

Let me know if this works.